# Python / pyodbc - WHERE statement to filter dates?

Tags: python, sql, datetime, pyodbc

I have used pydoc to fetch data from sql database.

I would like to use a WHERE statement to filter the dates. I have:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT isnull(SOP30200.SOPNUMBE,''), isnull(SOP30200.docdate,'') from SOP30200 where SOP30200.docdate > datetime.datetime(2015,1,1,0,0)")
```

and I get the error:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot find either column "datetime" or the user-defined function or aggregate "datetime.datetime", or the name is ambiguous. (4121) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Without the WHERE statement I successfully get the data. I did check the type of the "docdate" field that is pulled out and it is datetime.datetime.

EDIT: should also point out that the date that is extracted is in the form `datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 8, 0, 0)`

Comment: you have to use `sql server` specific `date` in the `where` clause `SOP30200.docdate > '1/1/2015'`

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I don't know what a sql server specific date is. Thanks

Comment: did you really mean `pydoc`?  I'm guessing from the tags that you meant `pyodbc`?

Comment: Sorry yes, title fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject/interpolate the date by using parameters. SQL server is attempting to run the SQL statement as is and expects a `datetime.datetime(..)` function to exist on the database.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT isnull(SOP30200.SOPNUMBE,''), isnull(SOP30200.docdate,'') from SOP30200 where SOP30200.docdate > ?", datetime.datetime(2015,1,1,0,0))
```

See http://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/ - Parameters section

Answer (score 2):

"datetime.datetime" is not the SQL function, is the class of Python standard library.

May be:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT isnull(SOP30200.SOPNUMBE,''), isnull(SOP30200.docdate,'') from SOP30200 where SOP30200.docdate > ?", datetime.datetime(2015,1,1,0,0))
```